# error when installing php unit

Tags: symfony, phpunit, composer-php

I'm working on an existing symfony project and need to use php unit.
When I tried to install it through composer with this command:

```
composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit ^5
```

But I got this error:

> proc_open (): CreateProcess failed, error code -267

[See screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1I0SY.jpg)

Comment: Your question needs editing to properly format the code. Also, in your case the image isn't super helpful - it'd be more helpful if the logging lines were just copied into your question (it helps with Google)

Comment: Please could you try running the command in verbose mode by adding the `-v` option? Then copy & paste (no image please) the exception trace in your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you refer to MS's [error code reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx), you'll see that error code 267 means that the directory name is invalid. So you've probably got an invalid directory reference in your configuration file.

Comment: Yes when I searched on the internet I found the same answer but I did not understand which directory name is wrong! give me more explanation please

Comment: @chouaibmehri Can you run your command with the `-v` argument and update your question with any additional output?

Answer (score -1):

Symfony has its own [PHPunit bridge component](https://symfony.com/components/PHPUnit%20Bridge) that adds features on top of the library.
Install it by running this command at the root of your project:

```
composer require --dev symfony/phpunit-bridge
```

You should then be able to run your test scripts with:

```
./vendor/bin/simple-phpunit
```